# How to solve unexpected token (<) error in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Related to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GieYIzvdt2U
I get the error:

```
    ERROR in ./leadmanager/frontend/scr/components/App.js 6:15
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:15)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | class App extends Component {
    |     render() {
    >         return <h1>React App</h1>
    |     }
    | }
     @ ./leadmanager/frontend/scr/index.js 1:0-35
```

when I run  `npm run dev`

You can find my code on https://github.com/bewaresandman/django

I'm pretty sure my code mirrors exactly the one from the tutorial, so I'm confused.

### Edit

The .babelrc and webpack.config.js files has been in the wrong folder. I fixed that. No the error:  `ERROR in ./leadmanager/frontend/scr/components/App.js Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError: C:\Users\meissners\eclipse-workspace\django\leadmanager\frontend\scr\components\App.js: Unexpected token (6:15)` occours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a webpack.config.js file.

webpack.config.js should contain:

```
module.exports = {
module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/env', "@babel/react"],
            }
          }}
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: I know... they have been in the wrong folder. I fixed that. But there is a new error occurring.

Comment: Actually your code does run!!

But why is this options term necessary? Or why does it work in the tutorial without it?

Comment: If you may have also been missing another file .babelrc that you can see on Brad's github. Adding the options here in the webpack config is the same as having a .babelrc file. I just realised I am missing something, enter `plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]` after the presets.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `jsx` file.

Rename your `index.js` and `App.js` with `index.jsx` and `App.jsx`.

Comment: @bewaresandman, have you installed all dependancies that the tutorial you mentionned show? You can follow this [tuto.](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/) or use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to generate react app then integrate it into your django project.

Comment: There'sn't a babel jsx-loader. Don't forget to recompile your code